# Conditional Statement Not Working in ie11 for Setting CSS Display

Tags: javascript, if-statement, internet-explorer

There's a strange occurrence with my conditional statement in ie11: if the first two conditions are false and code runs just the else, successMessage display is set to block as expected.

For some reason, let's say condition 2 is false, then is subsequently updated to true, the else code block doesn't set display to block, however the console did log the message.

Of course everything works well in modern browsers.

CSS:

```
.alert-success {
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
handleSubmit = () => {

  let successMessage = document.querySelector('.alert-success');

  if ( condition 1 ) {
   // do something
  } else if ( condition 2 ) {
   // do something else
  } else {
    successMessage.style.display = 'block'
    console.log('Did this render?');
  }

}
```

Comment: Please add all the relevant code, including the HTML.

Comment: As you did not posted your conditions, we are not able to test it with IE. You are using => (arrow function) in your code which is not supported in IE, so I hope that you are trans-piling your code for IE. Other thing you can try is for doing hard refresh by pressing CTRL+F5 key and try to delete the cache for IE and again try to make a test may help to solve the issue. If issue persist than try to inform us your conditions or try to post any code sample which can produce the issue may help us to narrow down the issue.